# Confirm Message Box Issue and Reset Button Issue

Tags: javascript, reset, confirm

My question is twofold.  First, I can't seem to figure out how to get my confirm message box's ok and cancel to work correctly.  The assignment calls for me to run the message, then validate my info, and if it validates, alert for ok or cancel.  I have done it the other way around (validate....message....alert), but I'm not sure how to do this.

Second, my reset button clears my info whether I hit ok or cancel??? Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--Document Head-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--Title Element-->
<title>Greendale Community College</title>
<!--Style Element-->
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Impact;
        color: green;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: green;
    }
</style>
<!--Script Element-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function submitRegistration() {
        var fName = document.registration.firstName.value;
        var lName = document.registration.lastName.value;
        var cwid = document.registration.cwid.value;
        var semester = document.registration.semester.value;
        var course = document.registration.courses.value;
        var section = document.registration.section.value;
        var major = document.registration.needForMajor.value;
        var semesterDisplay;
        if (semester == "fall")
            semesterDisplay = "Fall";
        if (semester == "spring")
            semesterDisplay = "Spring";
        if (semester == "summer")
            semesterDisplay = "Summer";
        var checkDisplay;
        if (document.registration.needForMajor.checked == true) {
            checkDisplay = "Course Needed For Major";
        }
        else {
            checkDisplay = "";
        }
        window.confirm("Student Name: " + fName + " " + lName + "   CWID: " + cwid + "   Semester: " + semesterDisplay + "   Course: " + course + "   Section: " + section + "   " + checkDisplay);
        if (fName == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your first name!");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(fName) == false) {
            window.alert("Your First Name must be non-numeric values!");
            return false;
        }
        if (lName == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your last name!");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(lName) == false) {
            window.alert("Your Last Name must be non-numeric values!");
            return false;
        }
        if (cwid == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your cwid!");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(cwid) == true) {
            window.alert("Your CWID must be numeric values!");
            return false;
        }
        var validateSemester = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (document.registration.semester[i].checked == true) {
                validateSemester = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (validateSemester != true) {
            window.alert("You must select a Semester!");
            return false;
        }
        if (course == "") {
            window.alert("You must select a Course!");
            return false;
        }
        if (section == "") {
            window.alert("You must select a Section!");
            return false;
        }   
        if (true) {
            window.alert("You have been registered for your course!");
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Your registration has been canceled.");
        }
    }
    function resetRegistration() {
        var resetForm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?");
        if (resetForm == true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    /* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Heading Element-->
    <h1>Greendale Community College</h1>
        <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256" /></center>
    <h2 align="center">Course Registration Page</h2>
<form action="FormProcessor.html" name="registration" method="get"
      onsubmit="submitRegistration();"
      onreset="resetRegistration()">
    <h3>Student Information Form</h3> 
    <!--Student Information-->
    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    CWID:<input type="text" name="cwid"><br>
    <h3>Semester</h3>
    <h4>(choose a semester)</h4>
    <!--Radio Buttons to Choose Semester-->
    <input type="radio" name="semester" value="fall" /> Fall 2018 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="semester" value="spring" /> Spring 2018 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="semester" value="summer" /> Summer 2018 <br />
    <h3>Courses</h3>
    <h4>(choose one course)</h4>
    <table>
        <!--Drop Down Box for Courses-->
        <tr><td style="background:white;border:0">Courses:</td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="courses" size="1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="CIS 110">Intro to CIS</option>
                    <option value="CIS 120">Application Prog I</option>
                    <option value="CIS 299">System Analysis I</option>
                    <option value="CIS 330">Web Programming I</option>
                    <option value="CIS 304">Cobol</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Sections</h3>
    <h4>(choose one section)</h4>
    <table>
        <tr><td style="background:white;border:0">Section Numbers:</td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="section" multiple="multiple" size="5">
                    <option value="001">CIS 110 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS110 GW1</option>
                    <option value="001">CIS 120 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 120 GW1</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 302 GW1</option>
                    <option value="001">CIS 304 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 303 GW1</option>
                    <option value="001">CIS 321 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 321 GW1</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 322 GW1</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="checkbox" name="needForMajor" />
    Check if the course is required for your major!<br />
    <!--Submit and Reset Buttons Created-->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="submitRegistration();" value="Submit"><br />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" onreset="resetRegistration();" value="Reset">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it:  I forgot to use return:

```
<form action="FormProcessor.html" name="registration" method="get"
      onsubmit="return submitRegistration();"
      onreset="return resetRegistration()">
```

instead of:

```
<form action="FormProcessor.html" name="registration" method="get"
      onsubmit="submitRegistration();"
      onreset="resetRegistration()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution. It should work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--Document Head-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--Title Element-->
<title>Greendale Community College</title>
<!--Style Element-->
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Impact;
        color: green;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: green;
    }
</style>
<!--Script Element-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function submitRegistration() {
        var fName = document.registration.firstName.value;
        var lName = document.registration.lastName.value;
        var cwid = document.registration.cwid.value;
        var semester = document.registration.semester.value;
        var course = document.registration.courses.value;
        var section = document.registration.section.value;
        var major = document.registration.needForMajor.value;
        var semesterDisplay;
        if (semester == "fall")
            semesterDisplay = "Fall";
        if (semester == "spring")
            semesterDisplay = "Spring";
        if (semester == "summer")
            semesterDisplay = "Summer";
        var checkDisplay;
        if (document.registration.needForMajor.checked == true) {
            checkDisplay = "Course Needed For Major";
        }
        else {
            checkDisplay = "";
        }

        if (fName == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your first name!");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(fName) == false) {
            window.alert("Your First Name must be non-numeric values!");
            return false;
        }
        if (lName == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your last name!");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(lName) == false) {
            window.alert("Your Last Name must be non-numeric values!");
            return false;
        }
        if (cwid == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your cwid!");
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(cwid) == true) {
            window.alert("Your CWID must be numeric values!");
            return false;
        }
        var validateSemester = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (document.registration.semester[i].checked == true) {
                validateSemester = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (validateSemester != true) {
            window.alert("You must select a Semester!");
            return false;
        }
        if (course == "") {
            window.alert("You must select a Course!");
            return false;
        }
        if (section == "") {
            window.alert("You must select a Section!");
            return false;
        }  
        var confirmation = window.confirm("Student Name: " + fName + " " + lName + "   CWID: " + cwid + "   Semester: " + semesterDisplay + "   Course: " + course + "   Section: " + section + "   " + checkDisplay);

        if (confirmation) {
            window.alert("You have been registered for your course!");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Your registration has been canceled.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    function resetRegistration() {
        var resetForm = confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?");
        if (resetForm == true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    /* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Heading Element-->
    <h1>Greendale Community College</h1>
        <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256" /></center>
    <h2 align="center">Course Registration Page</h2>
<form action="FormProcessor.html" name="registration" method="get" onsubmit="return submitRegistration();" onreset="return resetRegistration();">
    <h3>Student Information Form</h3> 
    <!--Student Information-->
    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    CWID:<input type="text" name="cwid"><br>
    <h3>Semester</h3>
    <h4>(choose a semester)</h4>
    <!--Radio Buttons to Choose Semester-->
    <input type="radio" name="semester" value="fall" /> Fall 2018 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="semester" value="spring" /> Spring 2018 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="semester" value="summer" /> Summer 2018 <br />
    <h3>Courses</h3>
    <h4>(choose one course)</h4>
    <table>
        <!--Drop Down Box for Courses-->
        <tr><td style="background:white;border:0">Courses:</td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="courses" size="1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="CIS 110">Intro to CIS</option>
                    <option value="CIS 120">Application Prog I</option>
                    <option value="CIS 299">System Analysis I</option>
                    <option value="CIS 330">Web Programming I</option>
                    <option value="CIS 304">Cobol</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Sections</h3>
    <h4>(choose one section)</h4>
    <table>
        <tr><td style="background:white;border:0">Section Numbers:</td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="section" multiple="multiple" size="5">
                    <option value="001">CIS 110 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS110 GW1</option>
                    <option value="001">CIS 120 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 120 GW1</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 302 GW1</option>
                    <option value="001">CIS 304 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 303 GW1</option>
                    <option value="001">CIS 321 001</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 321 GW1</option>
                    <option value="gw1">CIS 322 GW1</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="checkbox" name="needForMajor" />
    Check if the course is required for your major!<br />
    <!--Submit and Reset Buttons Created-->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that worked for the confirm.  I didn't think I could place it after, but it makes sense now.  Any ideas for the reset button?

Comment: Reset is also working in the solution I provided. Is it not working for you ?